# Animation trouble

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

So I am trying to animate something in python using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#----------------------------------------------
#This Section of code defines all of the important constants
timetot=1500*3
timestep=2

tdel=int(timetot/timestep)

rodleng=0.5
sizestep=0.01

sdel=int(rodleng/sizestep)

thermdiff=59/(450*7900)

matcon=timestep*thermdiff/(sizestep**2)
#----------------------------------------------
#stuff for ploting
X, T = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, sdel), np.arange(0, tdel))

colorinterpolation = 50
colourMap = plt.cm.jet
#------------------------------------------------
#Seting up initial state and Toeplitz matrix
mat=np.zeros(sdel)
np.put(mat, [0, 1], [1+2*matcon, -matcon])

mattoe=toeplitz(mat)
mattoe[0,0]=1
mattoe[0,1]=0

mattoe[-1,-1]=1
mattoe[-1,-2]=0

lu, piv=linalg.lu_factor(mattoe)

Rod=np.empty(sdel)
Rod.fill(20)
Rod[0]=1000
Rod[-1]=0

XTmat=np.ones((tdel,sdel))
XTmat[0, :]=Rod
#print(mattoe)
#-----------------------------------------

for i in range(1, tdel):
    delt=linalg.lu_solve((lu, piv), XTmat[i-1, :])
    XTmat[i, :]=delt

figa = plt.figure()
axa = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = axa.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,



def animate(i):
    dw=XTmat[i, :]
    x=np.linspace(0, 50)
    y=dw
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(figa, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=1000, interval=20, blit=True)




plt.show()
```

I am pretty sure my error is in the animate function since the rest of the code that creates XTmat works just fine and the rest of the animation code was ripped from here http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? Questions need a clear problem description.

Comment: I get still image of a coordinate system with nothing happening. When I try the code in the link everything works fine so it's not an issue with the settings. Apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your data ranges from 0 to 50 on the x axis and from 0 to 1000 on the y axis. Yet you limit your view to the ranges `xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2)`. There is no data in this range, hence the view stays empty.

Set the range to accommodate your data to see the data

```
axa = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(-2, 1000))
```